# how to show date of latest post in wordpress site?

Tags: date

i want to get the latest date of post in the homepage of my site.
in this code :

```
the_modified_date('d F Y');
```

date is different in different pages (For example page 1,2,...).
i want to show **just** the date of **latest post** that published.
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `get_the_date('d F Y');`

Answer (score 0):

The *last published post date* is:

```
$last_post_date = get_lastpostdate( 'blog', 'post' );
```

and the *last modified post date* is

```
$last_post_modified = get_lastpostmodified( 'blog', 'post' );
```

Here we use the `'post'` post type and the `'blog'` for the timezone.

Check out the documentation on [`get_lastpostdate`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_lastpostdate/) and [`get_lastpostmodified`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_lastpostmodified/) for more info.

Comment: how can i do this with sql query.i dont want to use wordpress functions.and i want to get the date and convert to persian calendar.

Comment: Please edit your question with all relevant info to avoid guesswork. I don't understand why you don't want to use the WordPress API that even  supports object caching? @Mehdi